# According to the Calvinist, why "believe" if something is known absolutely true?

Tags: reformed-theology, scriptures, infallibility

From this [link](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/infallibility-and-inerrancy/):

> Christians have said Scripture is infallible because they have
>   believed that God’s Word is incapable of erring and thus contains no
>   errors

The above sentences maybe to everyone else is easy to be understood by the Calvinist, but not for me (especially I'm not a Christian).

To me, God's Word is absolutely the truth. So to me it doesn't need to be believed. It's just like there is an ice cube in the fridge, then it doesn't make sense if I say *"I believe that ice cube is cold"*.

To me, the chronological order is like this :
Christians have believed that "X" writing is God's Words.
So, Christians believe that "X" writing is Scripture.
Since God's Words is infallible, then Christians believe that "X" writing is infallible.

So to me, the "believe" is not on the God's Words, but that "X" writing which is believed God's Words. The chronological order is : *IF there is a writing which is believed God's Words THEN that writing is infallible*. Later on : *Because this writing is believed God's Words then this writing is infallible*

Another quote from the same link:

> **If God never lies**, His Word never lies either. We can therefore trust
>   it to be free from all error

The same, it's confusing to me as the IF is on "God never lies", while my own chronological order the IF is on "the writing" ---> **IF this X writing is God's Words** THEN there is no lie in this X writing. (Why the "THEN" is like that ? because God never lies).

Because to me the IF is : *IF the writing is believed God's Words then the writing does not endorse anything untrue in the point of view whoever believe that writing is God's Words* then it raise a question: *how *"God never lies"* is the IF ?*

> *"The Christians have believed that God’s Word is incapable of erring"*

So my question is:
how *"God's Words is incapable of erring"* is a believe ?

---

Please ignore the question if the sentence in the quote is just a circular sentence like this :
*1. Christians have said Scripture is infallible because they have believed that Scripture is incapable of erring and thus contains no errors 

2. If Scripture never lies, Scripture never lies either. We can therefore trust it to be free from all error*

Comment: There is a difference between 1) my reading words in the bible that state that Christ died for sinners and accepting the fact of that, and 2) my believing on Jesus Christ for the salvation of my own soul such that I enter into a relationship with Jesus Christ, the Son of God, by faith. Your question seems not to be aware of the difference between these two states.

Comment: I think you got the grouping confused (which is understandable from the grammar): Scripture is infallible because God's word is incapable of erring is the argument. Christians say it because they believe it. So the statement had 2 if-thens smashed into 1 that made it confusing. As I think you would agree, believing something does not make it true.

Comment: @AlexStrasser, thank you for the explanation. Yes, if the sentence like as you wrote : _"Scripture is infallible because God's word is incapable of erring is the argument"_, I can quickly understand it. So maybe it's the type of English grammar which I don't understand as the article write : _"Scripture is infallible **because they have believed** that God’s Word is incapable of erring"_ .... then to me the "because they have believed that God's Word is incapable of erring" is the argument. (continue)

Comment: The other thing is the IF, I still don't understand why the IF is on "IF God never lies" not "IF this writing is God's Words"

Comment: A different representation would be "Christians have said x because they believe y," where y implies x. The way to group it would be "Christians [have said Scripture is infallible]  because [they have believed God's word is incapable of erring.] NOT "Christians have said [Scripture is infallible because they have believed God's word is incapable of erroring]." So they say it because they believe it. The grammar makes it ambigous but I know that is their argument. Hope that helps

Comment: For the "ifs", your argument only works with the "if God never lies". If a piece of writing is God's words, but God CAN/does lie, then the writing could have a lie in it. So the "if God never lies" part is required to conclude that a piece of writing has no lies in it.

Comment: And by the same token their argument requires that the writing is God's words. So their argument requires demonstrating that the writing is, in fact, God's Word. In sum, I think both parts are required to make an argument

Comment: @AlexStrasser, the problem with me is that I am unable to know what the article's writer mean on his text _"God's Words"_. That's why at the end of my question, I put  a note if the article's writer means on his text _"God's Words"_ = _"Scripture"_, an empty sentence ---> _"Scripture is infallible because it is believed Scripture is incapable of erroring"_, then my question is not valid.

Comment: @AlexStrasser, I am confused on _"but God can/does lie"_. But I think now I know that the problem is within me as to me _"IF God never lies"_ is strange. To me, it's just like saying a weird sentence : "IF ice cube is hot then one who touch it feel hot .... but ice cube is cold, then one who touch it feel cold either"_. (continue)

Comment: Illustration : Suppose I see a glass contains things which to me looks like ice cubes. I decided those things are ice cubes. So, I believe that the glass is cold. The logic order : IF those things are ice cubes then the glass is cold, where I don't even need to put "because ice cube is cold" or "IF ice cube is cold" as everybody knows that ice cube is cold.

Comment: The word "believe" has 6 different meanings in the English dictionary:  One of these meanings is in "I believe he has already left the party" - meaning "I think, assume, suppose" I have some evidence but it is not conclusive.  Another meaning is in the sentence "The man in the witness box in the court said he saw the accused do the crime.  He gave such a lot of evidence that the jury believed him".  Here the word "believe" has no element of doubt.. the jury fully believed the witness, there was no doubt in their minds. Here the word means "To accept (a statement or opinion as true or real).

Comment: If you know the ice cube is cold, why do you need to believe it?  Belief is often wrapped up in obedience.  When you put the ice cube in your drink to cool it down, you demonstrate your belief/knowledge.

Comment: It's just a bit strange for me if _"I believe 2+2 = 4"_ :).

Answer (score 2):

You can only be as confident about something as you are confident about the basis for that something. So just as you say, the Christians who believe in the infallibility of scripture **believe it**, they don't know it like they know that 2 + 2 = 4 or that gravity is real. It's not possible to prove the infallibility of scripture. There's no science that we can do to prove the infallibility of scripture. There's no [sound deductive argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning#Validity_and_soundness) to prove the infallibility of scripture. Neither can we prove that the scriptures are inspired by God or are God's word. The best we have is many lines of [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) that lead us believe that it is most likely that the scriptures are infallible.

If you see Christians saying that they "know" the scriptures are inspired or infallible, don't see that as a scientific or rigid deductive philosophical kind of knowledge, but instead the kind of relational knowledge you have when you say you know your parents or your spouse loves you. This kind of knowledge and belief is grown on the basis of years of experience of reliability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, curiousdannii. To be honest, I have difficulties to put it in English language. What I don't understand is not _"this X writing is believed God's Word"_ , or _"this X writing is believed infallible"_ , but _"God's Word is believed infallible"_. Since to me "God's Words is infallible" = "ice is cold", that's why I don't understand : _"**God**'s Word is believed infallible"_. I can understand to a sentence like this : _"**Pope**'s Word is believed infallible"_.

Comment: @karma Why do you find that hard to understand?

Comment: Because to me, God is different than Pope, curiousdannii.

Comment: @karma What about God is different that makes "God's word is infallible" hard for you to understand?

Comment: It's not that _"God's word is infallible"_ hard for me to understand, but _"[God's Word is infallible] is a believe"_ which made me can't understand. On the other hand, _"[Pope's Word is infallible] is a believe"_ I can understand. While _"[God's Word is infallible] is a believe"_ to me is like _"[ice is cold] is a believe"_, I can't understand.

Comment: @karma Ah, are you thinking that "God's word is infallible" is tautological? Well it's not, because some people believe God is not always truthful, or that God doesn't know everything, that he doesn't know the future, or that he makes mistakes in some other way.

Comment: If like that, then _"God's word is infallible"_ has a value "maybe yes maybe no".... the same thing with _"Pope's word is infallible"_ has a value "maybe yes maybe no". To me, _"God's word is infallible"_ doesn't have a value "maybe yes maybe no" ... while _"Pope's word is infallible"_ does have a value "maybe yes maybe no".

Comment: So, if to you, "God's word is infallible" is just an absolute truth, then what's the issue? If you're completely convinced, then great?

Comment: The issue is that as I don't understand when someone say "I believe ice is cold".

Answer (score 2):

> According to the Calvinist, why “believe” if something is known
>   absolutely true?

Philosophically speaking it is wise to live in agreement with truth.  2 + 2 = 4 is known to be true, so one would be a fool to live life believing that 2 + 2 = 29.  Secondly, our values and behaviors are shaped by what we believe whether it's true or not.

> To me, God's Word is absolutely the truth. So to me it doesn't need to
>   be believed.

I would argue that this is why it should be believed.  Think of all of the negative consequences in life that people experience for not believing what is true.  Furthermore God's word being absolutely true is independent of our belief.  Believing it's true doesn't make it true.

Comment: Your last sentence contains a powerful point that really does answer the question. It made me think of C.S. Lewis's words; "A man can no more diminish God’s glory by refusing to worship Him than a lunatic can put out the sun by scribbling the word, ‘darkness’ on the walls of his cell." And then, the Bible verse, "Let God be true, though every man a liar" (Romans 3:4). Believing in the utter integrity and truth of God is what every Christian needs to do. It follows that if God is true, then so is his word!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Lionsden. You wrote : _"I would argue that this is why it should be believed_". But to me, in order it fits with my question, I think your sentence should be : _"I would argue that [God's Word is the truth] is a believe"_. As I mentioned before, because to me "God's Word is infallible" = "ice is cold", that's why I don't understand that [God's Word is infallible] is a believe. Different story if the sentence [Pope's Word is infallible], so then to me [Pope's Word is infallible] is a believe.

Comment: I guess I'm getting a little lost in trying to understand what you are saying.  Let me try to clarify:  The Bible is God's word and is true AND I also believe that the Bible is God's words and is true.  There are many that believe that the Bible is not true.  The validity of the Bible is not found in the belief or lack of belief of the individual.  To me it sounds like you are saying, "It's common sense to believe that ice is cold"  I agree.  However there will be those that believe the contrary despite the evidence.

Comment: @Lionsden, you wrote : _To me it sounds like you are saying, "It's common sense to believe that ice is cold"_. I'm sorry, that's not what I mean. To me, "ice is cold" is not a believe, but is a knowledge which weird if put to a question like this : _is it true or not that "ice is cold ?"_ The same with "God's Word is infallible". The problem is "which one is the God's Word ?". Now if the answer is : "All the text in the Bible is God's Word" ---> then this is a believe. So to me, "God's Word is infallible" is not the same with "The Bible is infallible". (continue)

Comment: Put in a question : "Why the Bible is infallible ?".
The answer is not "Because God's word is infallible",
but "Because people believe that the Bible is God's Word".
That's why I don't understand why "God's word is infallible" is a believe,
while I do understand that "The Bible is infallible" is a believe.

Answer (score 2):

As a Christian who has come to believe that the Holy Scriptures are inerrant, I would like to explain a point that does not seem to have been raised so far. This hit me with real force only recently when reading a letter written by a Calvinist to a Christian friend. This quoted letter links ***three crucial truths that are bound up with the inerrancy of the Bible***. It uses one illustration to demonstrate the point, and good though your illustration of the ice cube is, this letter takes the matter into the spiritual realms, which all who profess belief in the Bible as the inerrant word of God should grasp.

The illustration is regarding the doctrine of the Trinity, which is a foundational belief of mainstream Christianity, and can only stand on what the Bible states about the being of God. Now, nobody so absolutely knows the truth of the Trinity doctrine as to be able to totally explain it. It won't be until believers are resurrected and stand before the throne of God that things will become much clearer. That, however, does not cause them to doubt the triune nature of the Godhead. They believe it. And that belief only comes from how the Bible which teaches it has been authored by one of the Persons in the Godhead - the Holy Spirit.

It is this **authorship** that is crucial when considering if the Bible is truly the inerrant word of God, to be totally believed, even though some parts of it cannot be known fully this side of eternity. Consider now how this Calvinist wrote on 19th November 1879 about the vital need for Christians to believe in the inerrancy of the Bible, because of who authored those writings, and why:

> "My Dear Friend - Do you understand the state of things in our poor
> church [in Scotland]? I do not. What I am afraid for is the doctrine
> of the Trinity... A church's hold on the doctrine of the Trinity is
> affected by her hold on the doctrine of the inspiration of Scripture.
> For it is in virtue of a truly inspired Word - His own Word - that the
> Holy Spirit acts as a person.
>
> It is a degradation to the Third Person of the Godhead to suppose that
> He would speak by the words or words of any person less than Himself.
> *He does not speak at all as a person by any word less than His own
> Word, or the Word of the Son, or the Word of the Father, all which are
> one.*
>
> To suppose the Spirit coming by a new and fresh revelation is of
> course Quakerism, but *in His coming by a previously written inspired
> Word, He acts as a person. As a person He speaks, enlightens,
> convinces, persuades, and renews. Deal falsely with personality here,
> then the Holy Spirit does not combine with the Second Person, but
> falls back upon an impersonal Deity - a Thing. You have merely what is
> implied in 'God is a Spirit', but Word is gone, Father is gone,
> Sonship is gone, Messiahship is gone, Mediatorial position is gone,
> infernal robbery has been committed, and the mists of darkness have
> settle down upon the church!*
>
> Yea, we are not a church at all, for we are robbed of a divine
> revelation, of a divine record. The privileges and position of a
> church are given *'chiefly because unto them were committed the oracles
> of God'* (Romans 3:2). Alas! that so many who ought to be teachers deal
> as falsely and irreverently with the oracles of God as a kitten
> playing with a cork.
>
> I am sorely afraid that there will be a great decline in our church.
> If you meet any after I am gone who do courageously stand for all
> revealed truth, give them my compliments, and tell them to be strong
> and of a good courage. Let them not yield to the current sentimental
> Christianity that would convert men's faith in a living, glorious,
> inexhaustible, infallible Word into empty-headed, empty-hearted
> speculations no better than Chinese puzzles or acted charades.
>
> God will avenge such trifling. 'The Scripture cannot be broken' (John
> 10:35) is the testimony of Him who is Himself the eternal Word. And
> will He suffer it to go unpunished if the divine truth - which He has
> in infinite condescension been pleased to make known to men by means
> of an infallibly inspired record - be broken up into bits and shreds,
> into fragments and fancies? And if the 'Lord will not hold them
> guiltless who takes his name in vain', (Exodus 20:7) He will not
> assuredly, hold that church guiltless which tolerates any profaning or
> abusing of that Word by which He hath made Himself known." *Letters of
> the Late Rev. Hugh Martin*, D.D. Free Pesbyterian Magazine, May 1879.

Because Calvinist and all Christians who believe the Bible to be absolutely true ***(inerrant) due to who its author is, "it effectually works also in you who believe"*** 1 Thessalonians 2:13. The author reveals the truth of that word, the record of the Word of God where his spoken words are combined with the entire revelation of God to humanity. **Confirmation of its inerrancy comes with belief - not the other way around.**

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of simple English.  If anything is true we believe it.  If its not true we don't believe it.  I believe the sun will come up tomorrow morning (unless our Lord returns today). It does not mean I do not know the sun will come up: I know it and so I believe it.

Unfortunately the idea has got around that "believing" something is when you decide you want that something to be true but do not have sufficient evidence to *know* it is true.  In fact, in Biblical language, "believing" is sometimes  *more* than just "knowing", not less.  The Devil knows that Jesus is the Son of God, but the Devil does not believe in or on the Son of God, meaning the Devil does not have a loving trust of the Son of God but rather hates the Son of God.

However, we believe many things because we have sufficient evidence to believe them to be true, even though we cannot absolutely prove them to be true.  For instance:

1. I believe the sun will come up tomorrow morning, even though I cannot absolutely prove it;  but, I am confident enough it will so that I live on the assumption that it will;
2. I believe this chair is reliable to sit on (I do not absolutely know it, but I am confident enough to sit on it, which means I have a very strong confidence in it);

"Believing" and "knowing" can often be considered to have the same meaning.  To say you *believe* something to be true is virtually the same as to say you *know* something to be true.

Comment: I'm sorry as it still difficult to me to understand it, Andrew. Suppose when I see the rain is pouring, I can't understand if I say "I believe the rain is pouring". The same thing like I say "I believe ice is cold" or "I believe God's Word is infallible"... but "I believe Pope's Word is infallible" or "I believe the Bible is infallible" I can understand it :).